# Why does it give me,"RuntimeError: threads can only be started once"?

Tags: python, pygame

If I run this code, it gives me the error message,

RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

A window pops up with the proper images but it is frozen and the screen crashes immediately. I am thinking that the thread is unable to work in the while loop but if that's the case how else would I fix the code.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import threading
pygame.init()

#Creates a window for the game
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,720))
#Names the window
pygame.display.set_caption("Pigeon Shootout")

#crosshair location
cx = 550
cy = 300
#pigeon1 location
p1x = 1000
p1y = 400
#pigeon2 location
p2x = 600
p2y = 400
#pigeon3 location
p3x = 200
p3y = 400

#Names images 
Background = pygame.image.load('Background.png')
Crosshair = pygame.image.load('Crosshair.png')
Pigeon = pygame.image.load('Pigeon.png')

def pigeon_spawn():
    #Generates random number than spawns pigeon acordingly
    num = random.randint(1,3)
    if num == 1:
        screen.blit(Pigeon, (p1x, p1y))
    elif num == 2:
        screen.blit(Pigeon, (p2x, p2y))
    else:
        screen.blit(Pigeon, (p3x, p3y))
    time.sleep(5)

#Puts pigeon_spawn run separately
pig = threading.Thread(target=pigeon_spawn)


run = True
while run == True:
    
    #imputs background and crosshair
    screen.blit(Background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(Crosshair, (cx, cy))
    
    #starts pigeon_spawn
    pig.start()
    
    #enables you to quit when you press the x at the top
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    #makes crosshair move with the arrow keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        cy -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        cy += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        cx -= 1.5
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        cx += 1.5
    screen.blit(Crosshair, (cx, cy))
    pygame.display.update()    

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach won't work. You cannot `blit` a *Surface* with the *Surface* indicator within a thread. The entire scene needs to be continuously redrawn in the application loop. Add a variable `pigeon_pos` variable that will store the `Pigeon` position, in global name space. Change the variable in a loop within the trade. `blit` the `Pigeon` in the application loop. Start the thread once befor the loop:

```py
pigeon_pos = (p1x, p1y)
run = True

def pigeon_spawn():
    global pigeon_pos
    while run:
        pigeon_pos = random.choice([(p1x, p1y), (p2x, p2y), (p3x, p3y)])
        print(pigeon_pos)
        time.sleep(5)

#Puts pigeon_spawn run seperatly
pig = threading.Thread(target=pigeon_spawn)
#starts pigeon_spawn
pig.start()

while run == True:
    #enables you to quit when you press the x at the top
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    #makes crosshair move with the arrow keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    cx += keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
    cy += keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]

    #imputs background and crosshair
    screen.blit(Background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(Crosshair, (cx, cy))
    screen.blit(Pigeon, pigeon_pos)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run the code in the function `pigeon_spawn` over and over again in a separate thread, why not just put that code in a loop such that the thread never exits?

If you really do need to launch a new thread over and over again, you want to create a new Thread object each time.  Just move the creation of the thread into the `while` loop:

```
while run == True:
    ...
    threading.Thread(target=pigeon_spawn).start()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

simply means that a thread only can be started once, not twice.

```
import threading
import time

def function():
    print("Hello!")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Bye")

#Starts thread1
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function)
thread1.start()

#Starts thread2
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=function)
thread2.start()

#Tries to start thread 2, but it is already started, so it will give a RunTimeError
thread2.start()
```

The console:

```
Hello!
Hello!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\test322.py", line 16, in <module>
    thread2.start()
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 865, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
Bye
Bye
```